# Is it worth to use Repository/Unit of work pattern when using Entity framework 6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Does it make sense to create another layer over the EF6 - Repository/UnitOfWork ?

In our custom repository we can add specific queries like GetTopXXX, GetLastUpdated, etc.

Bu we can do the same in Business Logic with LINQ on DBContext.

Comment: I would argue against the repository pattern. See the most popular answer here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180851/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to use a repository to **separate the logic that retrieves the data** in your situation.

Using the Repository pattern, very briefly, you will implement all your queries such as add, edit, update defined in your interface. And the way which you interact with the database is using **Entity Framework.**

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
   void Add(Product product);
}

public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
  private readonly DbContenxt _dbContext;

  public ProductRepository(DbContext dbContext)
  {
      _dbContext = dbContext;
  }

  public void Add(Product product)
  {
      var product = new Product() { Name = "Test" };

      _dbContext.Add(product);
      _dbContext.SaveChanges();                
   }
}
```